# SwitchCompat 's listener is not working , click is not responding

Tags: android, android-layout, switchcompat

When I click nothing happens and I do not know why it is. No error.
 I thought maybe change it to a standard switch not a compa but it did not help.

this is java code:

```
  SwitchCompat switchCompat2 = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch1);    
    switchCompat2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
                        @Override
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
        isChecked) {

                    Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
                    if(isChecked==true){
                        Status = mStatus[1];
                        Log.i("Debug", "Status is:  " + Status);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!"  + Status,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Status =  mStatus[0];
                        Log.i("Debug", "Status is:  " + Status);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast 
         message!"+   Status,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

this it the xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    style="@style/myCustomStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/T_Price"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TextShowAvaibleMoney"
    android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
    android:text="" />
```

Comment: What is not working for you? In the question @Override is misplaced. I am able to display the correspoding toast to get displayed. When I switch On and OFF. Only change i made in the layout file in "  style="@style/myCustomStyle"" I removed the style.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I have to put a style. What can I do if not style? Because I need to change design.

Comment: possible to post the style file. pls dont forget to upvote my comments.

Comment: Does not matter. I deleted the style and wrote it again and now it works. Thank you